# i tag doesn't show inside button tag

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

In my button element, text shows normally, but when I put a fontawesome icon inside it - it's like `visibility: hidden` is applied.

CSS

```
margin-left: 10px;
background: rgba(0, 196, 65, 100);
color: #fff;
font-weight: bold;
cursor: pointer;
transition: background 0.23s;
```

HTML:

```
<button type="submit" class="msger-send-btn">
    <i class="far fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
</button>
```

When I changed browser zoom I saw this:
[image]

Comment: there is space used by icon but it is invisible.

Comment: On the picture i also trying to do label with input characters length like 20/100

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the solid version (`fas`) and not the regular one (`far`)

```css
button {
  margin-left: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 196, 65, 100);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.23s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/css/all.css">
<button type="submit" class="msger-send-btn">
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right fa-5x"></i>
</button>
```

The regular version is only available in [the PRO package](https://fontawesome.com/icons/arrow-circle-right?style=regular)

But if you want to have the visual of the regular version you can build it with two icons:

```css
button {
  margin-left: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 196, 65, 100);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.23s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/css/all.css">
<button type="submit" class="msger-send-btn">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-3x" >
      <i class="far fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-arrow-right fa-stack-1x"></i>
    </span>
</button>
```

Related: [Font Awesome 5 - how to put an icon inside a circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60934284/8620333)

Comment: problem is that i have pro version... the icon is working in other tags like div etc. but doesn't work in button tag

Comment: i test sth what you typed. Anyways thank you for answer

Comment: @TimothyHill share your full code then, you have for sure more CSS involved

Comment: and yes... i use template because it's a creative work(school project in the grade 8th) and i don't care about it because i need to do it fast (protection will be on may 14). Sorry if my english is not very good(i live in Estonia).